# Storage issue in azure kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Our Current Infra-

We are running our pod in AKS on [Standard_F64s_v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/fsv2-series) which is having disk space of 512GB and ephemeral OS disk space is 60 Gb.

Doubt

1. Is ephemeral OS disk different from machine disk? [AKS]
2. When a docker image is downloaded to run in a container where is it get downloaded in OS disk or in machine disk? [AKS]
3. Does each pod download a new docker image, or same is getting downloaded by some process in a node and getting reused by all pods within that node or some other way? [Kubernetes]

Answer (score 1):

> Is ephemeral OS disk different from machine disk? [AKS]

Yes, ephemeral OS disks in Azure Kubernetes cluster are the local disks that are covered/come with the Virtual machines of nodes. They are not saved to Azure Storage and hence the latency in read/write operations is very low.

Data life in Ephemeral disks is only with the life of the machine/node itself.

More about epheremal disks at [Microsoft Documentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/everything-you-want-to-know-about-ephemeral-os-disks-and-azure/ba-p/3565605)

> When a docker image is downloaded to run in a container where is it get downloaded in the OS disk or in the machine disk? [AKS]

Honestly, I would ask someone who is certain on this to answer. However, In my understanding, it should be stored in the OS disk if the managed disk is not mounted on `/var/lib/docker` as that's the default location for docker to store image data.

> Does each pod download a new docker image, or same is getting downloaded by some process in a node and getting reused by all pods within that node or some other way? [Kubernetes]

It's not about the pod, it's about the node actually. So each node maintains its image storage and hence as per the configured image-pull policy they will pull/store the images. Also, you might know already that images are versioned with tags and if a new tag is configured then it will be pulled on the respective nodes for each pod.

For Example: if the image pull policy is configured as `IfNotPresent` then container runtime will first check if the image is available on the node locally, If it is available then will use from the locally saved images else pull it from the configured container registry.